# Generate private key at build time using shell script only once & save into keychain

Tags: ios, bash, security, cryptography

I genereted private keys using Apple's built in Security framework.

But as per client, he wants to generate at build time using shell script,
save into keychain only once till app installed.

My doubt is can we achieve keychain using script in iOS?
I don't have experience in scripting, I written following script after internet search.

I tried following way but it shows error non exit code zero.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the file name for the private key
private_key_file="private_key.pem"

# Generate a private key with RSA algorithm and save it to a file
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out "$PROJECT_DIR/$private_key_file" -aes256
```

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think we can generate keys by openssl command , but not sure we can access keychain via script

Comment: As I understand your question, you want to load a key into the keychain on the iOS device that is running your app. You would need to do this in code in your app the first time it runs.  This means that your private key would need to be embedded in your app, which is not secure.  There is no real way to deliver "secrets" in an app such that they cannot be extracted by an attacker.  Depending on the value of the private key, it may be OK to include it in your app; You need to make that determination

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for your answer, can we do run shell script from code and generate private keys?

Comment: Yes, but it isn't clear why you would want to do that you would get a new private key in a file each time you built the app. You could include this pen file in your bundle, but then each version of your app you release to the store would have a different private key. What would happen when a user updates the app?  Should they use the new key or keep using the old key?  What is the purpose of this key?

Comment: @Paulw11 as we need secure communication with server , only encrypted data needs to be transmitted on server
So that's why we need private key for encryption, which generates only once app first time launch.

Comment: But how is the server going to know how to decrypt the data?  Why not just rely on TLS(Https)?  If you are using symmetric key encryption then it also needs to have the key, but the key will depend on which version of the app the user has (since you generate a new key each time you generate a new build).  Also, since the private key is embedded in your app it isn't really a secret.  It seems like you are going to a lot of trouble to solve a problem that HTTPS already solves and it isn't going to work anyway.  Security is hard.  Don't try and build your own.